# Sorting randomly generated SVGs in descending size

Tags: javascript, for-loop, svg, random

Currently my javascript is this:

```
var svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  var x = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1)

  var rect = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'rect');
  rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'height', x);
  rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'width', x);
  rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke-width', '5')
  rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', 'red');
  rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke', 'black');
  document.getElementById('svgSquare').appendChild(rect);
}
```

and my HTML is this :

```
<svg id="svgSquare"></svg>
```

This code displays the number of squares I want but it stacks them on top of each other with them all starting at the same point. How do I take the random squares made from this for loop and display them in stacked descending order. Unsure where to go at this point and not sure if I'm even asking the right question.

Comment: You may save the rects in an array and sort the array. Creating a class of objects rect may be useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create your random `arr` then use `arr.sort()` and then loop through your sorted `arr` and for each size add the `rect` to the svg and offset in the X-direction and Y-direction alternately to create this kind of pattern?:

[image]

Here's the code also in this JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/alexander_L/q5umrgnv/41/:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
  var offsetY = 0;
  var offsetX = 0;
  var arr = [0];
  for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    var x = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1)    
    arr.push(x);
  }  
  //sort the array ascending:
  arr.sort((a, b) => a - b);

  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {  
    var x = arr[i];
    console.log(i, x);
    var rect = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'rect');
    rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', offsetY);
    rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', offsetX);
    rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'height', x);
    rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'width', x);
    rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke-width', '5')
    rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', 'red');
    rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke', 'black');
    document.getElementById('svgSquare').appendChild(rect);
    if (i % 2 == 0){
      offsetY += x;
    } else {
      offsetX += x;
    }

    document.getElementById('svgSquare').setAttribute("height", (offsetY + x) + "px");
    document.getElementById('svgSquare').setAttribute("width", (offsetX + x) + "px");

  }
});
```

Comment: A few tweaks to this and I was able to get exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome, if my post answered your question please consider to mark it as the correct answer and up-vote it :) thanks

Comment: No worries & Thanks :) See you around!